# Changing Jquery script in a web page

Tags: jquery, html

I have tried to refresh the jquery script inside a web page. i.e changing various jquery version scripts by selecting a drop down control.

I tried the below way to change the jquery version but it doesn't work

```
//This is how the script referred at initial load     
<script id="jqlink" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I rendered a drop down with various jquery version as its datasource and when I select the drop down value, it needs to be change the script's src value and after that the web page needs to be work based on the selected jquery CDN.

```
function changeJQ(version){
   $("#jqlink").attr("src", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + version + "/jquery.min.js")
}
```

Is it necessary to reload the page or anything needs to perform for this functionality?

Comment: Jquery scripts are loaded at the time of your page loaded to browser. You can not control it by this way.
May i know the purpose of doing this?

Comment: @Dhruv: Thanks for the update.  I need to test the web control behavior with various jquery version scripts, so that only I tried this way.

Comment: similar like  https://jsfiddle.net gives options to select jquery version etc?

Comment: Yes, but just need to test with jquery is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. and check the inspect element after it execute. 
let me know if you have any  doubt

Some how you have to call the function to change the jquery version,

you can also call the function by clicking on some button.
like this

```
<html>
    <head>   
        <script id="jqlink" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>     
        <input type="text" name="version" id="version"/>
        <button type="button" id="ChangeVersion"> Change jQuery Verison</button>

        <div id="CurrentjQuery"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#CurrentjQuery").html($("#jqlink").attr('src'));
        });

        function changeJQ(version){
            $("#jqlink").attr("src", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + version + "/jquery.min.js")
            $("#CurrentjQuery").html($("#jqlink").attr('src'));
         }
        $(document).on("click","#ChangeVersion",function () {

            if($("#version").val().trim() == ''){
                alert("Please enter version");
                return false;
            }
            else{                
                changeJQ($("#version").val().trim());
            }             
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Or this will be a simple way .

```
<html>
    <head>   
        <script id="jqlink" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>        
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function changeJQ(version){
                $("#jqlink").attr("src", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + version + "/jquery.min.js")
             }

             changeJQ("1.10.5");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```